# Is it possible to use "AND " and "NOT" condition in the same grep command

Tags: linux, grep

I need to search in a directory of files which has pattern1 but not pattern2.

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  Do you want all occurrences of pattern1, in all files that do not contain pattern2 anywhere?  Or do you want all occurrences of pattern1, excluding *lines* that also contain pattern2?  My answer assumes the former, everyone else seems to be assuming the latter.

Comment: Are you parsing `ls`?  You should use `find` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep pattern1 $(grep -L pattern2 *)
```

is probably the easiest way to do it, if I understand correctly what you want.  `-L` means "print just the names of all files that do *not* contain this pattern"; it's the inverse of `-l`.  This will not work correctly if you have files with whitespace or some other shell metacharacters in their names.

Answer (score 2):

look at the -v flag to grep.   You can pipe multiple calls to grep together, which is probably the simplest approach here.  One to look for pattern1, and another to grep -v pattern2.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a grep to the first grep:

```
grep -r "this pattern" /path | grep -v "not this patten"
```

HTH

Francisco